# Boost.Test check whether a pointer is null

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost.test

I have the following test :

```
BOOST_CHECK_NE(pointer, nullptr);
```

The compilation fails due to

> /xxx/include/boost/test/tools/detail/print_helper.hpp:50:14: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘std::nullptr_t’)

What is wrong and how should I test for null pointers ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest check for a pointer being non-null is this:

```
BOOST_CHECK(pointer);
```

A null pointer implicitly converts to `false`, a non-null pointer implicitly converts to `true`.

As to what the problem with your use case is: `nullptr` is not a pointer type, it's of type `std::nullptr_t`. It can be converted to any pointer type (or pointer to member type). However, there is no overload of `<<` for inserting `std::nullptr_t` into a stream. You would have to cast `nullptr` to the appropriate pointer type to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in error message, `nullptr` has ambiguous overloads.

```
BOOST_CHECK(pointer);
```

or

```
BOOST_CHECK_NE(pointer, static_cast<decltype(pointer)>(nullptr));
```

should do the job.