# C++98 proper check for a null pointer

Tags: c++98, null-pointer

[C++11](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/nullptr_t/) introduced the `nullptr` keyword, which I don't have available.

I suppose there is the `NULL` macro from C, which I read about using in C++ from some stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176989/do-you-use-null-or-0-zero-for-pointers-in-c) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_null_pointers.htm), but I'm still unsure what's the proper way of checking for a null pointer in this older standard of C++.

I essentially want to be able to write this code for my test case with Boost Test:

```
aWrapperDataStructure x;
BOOST_CHECK_NE(x.get_ptr(), static_cast<decltype(x.get_ptr())>(nullptr));
```

But maybe, as Tutorials Point suggested, something like this is more appropriate given the constraints:

```
BOOST_CHECK(x.get_ptr()); //true when not NULL
```

Something about that throws me off though, so I'm wondering what the best practice is here. If it's somewhere online, or on SO, it's been long buried and I can't find it. Thank you!

Comment: I made a mistake in my `nullptr` example. Correcting it as per the example I saw here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673724/boost-test-check-whether-a-pointer-is-null, which also more or less answered my question entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't feel right answering my own question here because I'm definitely not qualified to, but I read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185821/how-do-we-check-if-a-pointer-is-null-pointer?rq=1) (It's still tagged C++ despite newer standards) from James Kanze:

> If you use g++, you really should use `NULL`.

which is definitely good enough for me. I found these *expressions* for checking a null pointer though:

```
(p != NULL) //requires #include <stddef.h>

(p != 0)

(p)
```

And of these 3, the last one which I had mentioned in my question, does an implicit conversion from a pointer to a bool (*hiss*). Using `!=` and `==` at least does an explicit conversion to a bool, and moreover, using `NULL` shows your intent of checking a null pointer.

Therefore, I think even when not using g++, the expression `(p != NULL)` is the most appropriate way for the older C++ standard. (However, I'll still cede to someone else's expertise and mark their answer; I'm just an undergraduate student.)

Comment: It's the style equivalent of a micro-optimisation question. How you test for null is highly unlikely to make any difference to the readability of your code, and you see all methods in production C++.

Comment: Yes, but I can't tell you how many times my code wouldn't compile because of this stupid issue. Even something like `BOOST_CHECK_NE(p, NULL);` wasn't allowed because "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer". Yet, `BOOST_CHECK(p != NULL)` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Ah. Just had to cast `NULL` to the right pointer type. I'm still new to this :)

Answer (score 0):

g++ use C++11 by default for some time now.

Therefore you can use `nullptr` and be "modern" as well as type safe.

If you have to be pre-C++11 portable `NULL` is best.